# Is there a reference for the pasurams sung during the jeeyar sevai at Tirupati?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, alwar, venkateshwara, tirupati, divya-prabhandham

Every morning, there is a special darshan at Tirupati for the jeeyar (head) of a traditional mutt at Tirumala. Other Srivaishnavite brahmins too may be permitted to accompany the jeeyar to serve as extras and join in the chants, provided they satisfy certain conditions.

In this session, various pasurams from the Divya Prabandam (Tamil Srivaishnavite poetry of the Alwars) are sung. While I know some of the pasurams, I am looking for a systematic list of all the chants sung in this jeeyar sevai, in the order in which they are sung.

Thanks!